# simple PHP preg_replace question

Tags: php, regex

Here's a simple preg_replace

```
$string = 'src="index.php';
$string = preg_replace("/(src=('|\")+[^(http:|https:)])/i", "src=\"http://domain.com/", $string);
echo $string;
```

I expect the result to be `src="http://domain.com/index.php` but it turns out to be `src="http://domain.com/ndex.php`.

I must be missing something here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a really messed up regex. What are you trying to achieve exactly? It looks like if the URL doesn't start with http or https you want to add the domain? If so, you're quite a bit off:

```
$string = preg_replace('/src=(\'|")?(?!htts?:)/i', 'src="http://domain.com/');
```

should be a lot closer to the mark.

What does this regex do? It looks for:

- `src=`
- optionally followed by either `'` or `"`
- *not* followed by `http:` or `https:`
- all done case insensitive

**Note:** `{?!...)` is called a *negative lookahead* and is one example of a [zero-width assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). "Zero-width" here means that it doesn't consume any of the input. In this case it means "not followed by ...".

What does your regex do? It looks for:

- `src=`
- one *or more* `'` or `"` characters
- any one character that *isn't* any of `(http:|https:)` (that's what the `[^...]` construct means)
- all case insensitive

**Note:**

```
[^(http:|https:)]
```

is equivalent to:

```
[^():https]
```

meaning any character that is *not* one of those characters.

Comment: Just something minor, the single quote will need escaping

Answer (score 0):

The construct `[^(http:|https:)]` is incorrect. It matches any character except `(`, `h`, `t`, `p`, `:`, `|`, `s`, or `)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'src="index.php'; $string = preg_replace("/src=('|\")?(?!htts?:)/i", "src=\"http://domain.com/", $string); echo $string;
```

try this: I tested it myself